# Reference request: comprehensive handbook of combinatorial formulae

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am searching for an handbook that collects a comprehensive list of formulae in combinatorics. Could you point out one such reference?

Comment: http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/

Comment: @Myself, nice. Dal, look at this from http://oeis.org/wiki/Sequences_from_Stanley%27s_Enumerative_Combinatorics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "comprehensive list of formulae in combinatorics". But there are some useful resources. Henry W Gould's [homepage](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/); John Riordan's book, Combinatorial Identities; Ken Rosen's Handbook of Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics; Comtet's Advanced Combinatorics; Handbook of Combinatorics by Graham et al.

Comment: Thank you, Professor. Gould's material seems to be what I was looking for.